# Why does an error occur when Angular 2 is switched to Angular 5?

Tags: angular

Help Wanted.
When switching from Angular 2 to Angular 5, an error occurred:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9902)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:13951)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13925)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14754)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14656)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (GeneralFormComponent.html:4)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14638)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:13763)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14116)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14068)
```

The console references an error on the line in the GeneralFormComponent:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.guid" name="guid">
```

After debugging, I realized that the component was called 2 times. At the first time, the model was only initialized and the model in fact was empty, and at the second time in the model came data from the database.
I assume that this error stems from the fact that some data came and they were abruptly replaced by new ones.

Help solve the problem.

Comment: You likely need an `*ngIf` somewhere to keep this error from occurring. Can't tell where without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I tried to use *ngIf, but did not help

Answer (score 0):

Building on Richards' suggestion

Perhaps this would help?

`<ng-container *ngIf="model != null && model.guid!=null">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.guid" name="guid">
</ng-container>`

Comment: Now the error was repeated in this line:
<ng-container *ngIf="model != null && model.guid != null">

Error text: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined